# Windows using VPN even when using IP address to access share

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm connecting from my Windows 10 machine to a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine in the same subnet. I also have an OpenVPN connection that goes to the office and the server also has its own connection.

When I'm accessing files on the server sometimes the connection goes through the VPN without me noticing. Of course this is not what I want since I have a gigabit connection to it in the local network and a lot slower through the VPN.

The strange thing about this is that I have set the server name in the hosts file to point to the local IP. And even stranger: even if I write `\\192.168.23.45\share` to Explorer address line the connection will actually go through the VPN (where it would be `\\10.12.34.56\share`)!

The only way I can get it to work properly is to disable the VPN, access files and then maybe enable VPN.

Is there some way to tell Windows that it should *never* attempt to use the VPN address for that server and *always* use the local network address?

The metrics for local route is, for example, 276 and for the VPN connection it's set to 5120 in an attempt to stop it from using it. Still Windows decides to ignore my given IP and use the IP that goes through the VPN.

Local network is 192.168.23.0/24 and VPN network is 10.12.34.0/24 so they are completely separate. No IPv6 on the VPN, local network has the local IPv6 addresses.

I can also stop OpenVPN while transfering files or doing whatever with the file shares. The Windows 10 machine will just wait a moment, then switch to the non-VPN connection and continue. And if I restart it the transfers will switch to the VPN connection. So Windows is internally choosing which IP to use to that server, not just using the IP I give.

The server has also now been upgraded to 2016 but that hasn't changed anything. The problem is somehow in the Windows 10 machine. This also doesn't happen at all from another Windows 10 machine in the same subnet, same domain with the same OpenVPN configuration. But that machine is usually with ethernet and/or better wifi connection.

Edit: At some point it seemed that Windows sees OpenVPN adapter as 1Gbps network and thinks it’s better than wifi, which is of course not 1Gbps. So is there a way to say “ignore this functionality”, if that is the case? Or say “VPN is actually a bad bad network, use only if you can’t use other ways”?

Edit: Here's the routing table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.23.254   192.168.23.220    266
       10.12.34.0    255.255.255.0     10.100.101.1    10.100.101.14   5120
     10.100.101.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     10.100.101.14    356
    10.100.101.14  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.100.101.14    356
   10.100.101.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.100.101.14    356
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    VPN.SERVER.IP  255.255.255.255   192.168.23.254   192.168.23.220   5120
     192.168.23.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.23.220    266
   192.168.23.220  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.23.220    266
   192.168.23.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.23.220    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.23.220    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.100.101.14    356
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.23.220    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.100.101.14    356
===========================================================================
```

As mentioned, accessing `\\192.168.23.45\share` connects to `\\10.12.34.56\share` instead if the VPN is on. Just like any other machine in `192.168.23.0/24` block if they also have a `10.12.34.0/24` address available. If VPN is off it goes fine. If I turn it off while copying files it'll switch to `192.168.23.45` transparently. If I turn it back on it will again switch to `10.12.34.56` transparently. Routing is fine everywhere and naturally any server that only has `10.12.34.0/24` address is accessible just fine, just like any machine in `192.168.23.0/24` that does *not* have address in the VPN block is fine.

The server has the two IPs set in internal DNS, nothing anywhere else, so if Windows wants to resolve something it can and will get either nothing or both IPs, so that will not explain any behavior.

Here's a shot of Wireshark dumping information. As you can see, I've gone to `\\192.168...` path but Windows still asks `10.100.101.21` for information about the shares and files. So there's no question it literally uses the other IP of the server, not the one I manually write to the address bar.

[image]

As I wrote before, the wifi adapter is 300Mbps and VPN is 1Gbps and I do remember sometimes the VPN showing as lower speed and then this didn't happen. So it may be Windows assuming the 1Gbps VPN is better than the wifi to connect to the server, even though it obviously is not 1Gbps connection. But I can't find any information about this nor how to disable it.

The TAP adapter doesn't have settings to change it from 1Gbps to something smaller if that would help.

`arp -a`:

```
Interface: 192.168.23.220 --- 0x5
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.23.45         d8-cb-8a-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.23.254        c4-6e-1f-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.23.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

Interface: 10.100.101.14 --- 0x7
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.100.101.1          e2-e0-45-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  10.100.101.21         00-ff-52-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  10.100.101.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I also dumped again what happens when I start copying a file *without VPN* and then turn VPN on in the middle. There's DNS queries about the `domain.local` (not the server I'm connected to, just the domain), WPAD queries, SRV record queries, NBNS registration of my machine to the network, Negotiate Protocol Request/Response, Session Setup Request/Response, and then the file data starts flowing through the VPN instead if direct connection without interruption.

Comment: is the OpenVPN network's subnet different than the subnet you're trying to use with the local server?  Have you tried simply using `route` to add a route to that IP through that interface?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, they are completely separate. Edited the question. There is of course a route to the local network since I can access it fine if the VPN is off. It just somehow goes the wrong route sometimes when the VPN is on, even with the IP address.

Comment: Did you try to disable IPv6 on the local network ? You might only have set routes for IPv4.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, disabling IPv6 doesn't change anything. And OpenVPN doesn't do IPv6 anyway, it's all IPv4.

Comment: The question here is Windows routing. Questions: (1) Why is the metric at 276? (2) What are the IPv4 Properties on both adapters? (if they are not automatic), (3) How can you be sure that it's accessing the VPN (for DNS I assume) ?

Comment: @harrymc The metric changes, it’s automatic. Today it’s not 276. LAN is much lower but regardless what I put for manual value it doesn’t matter. All settings are automatic, LAN gets settings from DHCP, OpenVPN from server. Just like other machine.

Comment: @harrymc Could you clarify what exactly is missing of those? Which details of of the network adapter?

Comment: At least the routing table when the problem arrives (`route print`), which example IP address causes the problem, and the output of `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: @harrymc Added the info

Comment: What happens if you lowered the metric of the first route? A nice tool is [NetRouteView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_route_view.html). The output of `ipconfig /all` might be useful.

Comment: Can you explain how you know it is connecting through one IP address or another. If you type one address in the explorer bar and it connects to a different IP that is very strange. Therefore, an important detail is how you know this? Have you run wireshark to see what is actually happening on the wire? This may be an ARP issue or the destination server may be routing return packets through the VPN even when the originate from the local network. So the problem can be in both places. It would help to see the entire connection established in wireshark on both machines.

Comment: @Appleoddity Because the network traffic goes through the VPN. That’s how I know. And yes, I have dumped the network traffic. It wouldn’t send local traffic through the VPN with a local IP address because there’s no route from the remote network to the local address range not is there any gateway there.

Comment: @Appleoddity I added a screenshot showing the dump. I told Explorer to go to `\\192.168...` and yet there's traffic here and all the files I access go through the VPN immediately.

Comment: Ok. This doesn't show the establishment of the connection. There is first an ARP request and response for both systems, and a 3 way TCP handshake. Windows will not use a different IP to connect to from what you typed in. So something is redirecting it somewhere else. That will show up in the connection establishment. I'm positive that an ARP request will go out that says "Who has 192.168.x.x" which will indicate Windows is trying to use the IP you typed in. Somewhere between there and the completion of the connection it is redirected.

Comment: Also, these are all internal, private IPs. There is zero value to anyone seeing that information, there is no reason to hide it. If you want to obfuscate machine names or some type of identifiable information, I understand, but internal private IPs are not personally identifiable.

Comment: Immediately after establishing the connection the `arp -a` command output could help as well.

Comment: @Appleoddity Added arps too. And yes, Windows *does* use something else. As I've said many times, I can stop the VPN and Windows will just jump to the other IP. Start VPN, it jumps to using the other IP. It literally *does* switch IPs because SMB does that. It's not just IP traffic, it's SMB traffic and something there is doing this. If I ping it, this doesn't happen. Remote desktop, doesn't happen. SMB only.

Comment: You can see the ARP entry for 192.168.23.45 which confirms that windows has very recently tried to communicate with that address. As I said, the answers are in the wireshark trace. Windows is without a doubt making its initial request to 192.168.23.45 as you have typed in. In the wireshark trace is the answer for when and why it changes to a different IP. The info I need isn’t in the information you provided.

Comment: I have added another answer.

Comment: Is the server a domain controller or running DFS? You can check for DFS referral issues using `dfsutil /PktInfo` on a client with RSAT tools installed. DFS will absolutely micromanage connections like this for you, and can substitute an entirely different server in for an IP. Only works for SMB connections, ignores hosts file, etc

Comment: @user19702 That command run on the client says “0 entries”, on the server it says there’s an entry for `\domain\sysvol`

Comment: Do you have Windows updates enabled or disabled? I am just curious if you have build 1909 already with the [KB4554364](https://borncity.com/win/2020/03/31/windows-10-updates-fixes-vpn-bug/) update released March 30, 2020

Answer (score 2):

(*Old answer from when the question was written differently*.)

You might be encountering a DNS wait on the VPN, because of the way that
Windows 10 issues DNS requests for VPN split-dns,
which is very different from previous Windows versions.

Windows 10 issues DNS queries in parallel to all adapters,
then is supposed to take the first answer to arrive.

Unfortunately, it may, rather than take the first answer,
wait for all answers.
If this not-new bug was not yet fixed,
to return the behavior as much as possible to that of previous Windows
versions, do the following registry modifications :

**DisableSmartNameResolution** (DWORD)

In registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient`.
The value is 1 to disable, 0 to enable smart resolution.
From [Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/windows-group-policy-encyclopedia/2718dc40b3ecea129213e7eca29b7357/turn-off-smart-multi-homed-name-resolution) :

> Specifies that a multi-homed DNS client should optimize name
>   resolution across networks. The setting improves performance by
>   issuing parallel DNS link local multicast name resolution (LLMNR) and
>   NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NetBT) queries across all networks. In the event
>   that multiple positive responses are received the network binding
>   order is used to determine which response to accept.If you enable this
>   policy setting the DNS client will not perform any optimizations. DNS
>   queries will be issued across all networks first. LLMNR queries will
>   be issued if the DNS queries fail followed by NetBT queries if LLMNR
>   queries fail. If you disable this policy setting or if you do not
>   configure this policy, setting name resolution will be optimized when
>   issuing DNS LLMNR and NetBT queries.

**DisableParallelAandAAAA** (DWORD)

In registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters`.
The value is 0 to enable, 1 to disable
DNS A and AAAA queries from executing in parallel on all configured DNS servers,
with the fastest response theoretically accepted first.

You may also set these policies by using PowerShell :

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" -Name DisableSmartNameResolution -Value 1 -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters‌​" -Name DisableParallelAandAAAA -Value 1 -Type DWord
```

Comment: I don’t know how DNS would relate. Note: I access *by IP* and Windows goes through the VPN still. I have set up IPs in hosts files. Still goes through VPN. I can start VPN *after* starting to move files to shares and it will jump to VPN. DNS wouldn’t affect any of these.

Comment: We are talking of a Windows bug or deficiency introduced in Windows 10, and these fixes turn off much of the new options. Wouldn't hurt to try.

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN should have a "virtual" network adapter installed on your computer alongside your other physical adapters.

Try to change the priority of those network adapters as seen in this article:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/

You want the OpenVPN interface to be a larger number (lower priority) than your physical adapter.

Comment: Get-NetIPInterface says my OpenVPN connection's InterfaceMetric is 35 while the LAN interface is 25. So if should be using the LAN before OVPN?

Comment: Yes, this sounds correct. It was worth a shot I guess. :)

Comment: Even with priority of 5000 and the wifi having 300 it still chooses to go through the VPN, so this didn't help the situation unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `OpenVPN` Client for your VPN Connection, then you can add custom routes for specific domains/IPs.

So that once you add the route, the connection to those domains/IPs will go through the specific route.

A route syntax for OpenVPN Config file is :

```
route [ip or website name] [subnet mask] [your gateway]
```

So in your case, if the gateway is 192.168.23.1 then you'll need to add this line to your OpenVPN Config file :

```
route 192.168.23.45 255.255.255.0 192.168.23.1
```

Comment: As I said, there is a route. The client just chooses to use a different IP to connect to that server and use the VPN route.

Answer (score 1):

You have two network interfaces on your computer, Ethernet and VPN,
and you are using SMB for accessing a network share on one specific
network interface, but find yourself using a share by the same name,
but on the other network interface.
Using an IP address for the computer hosting the share does not help.

[Server Message Block (SMB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)
is a very old protocol, dating from much before the Internet and IP.
Microsoft's article
[Direct hosting of SMB over TCP/IP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/204279/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcp-ip)
has this phrase:

> NetbiosSmb is a global device, and is **not bound on a per-adapter basis**. This means that direct-hosted SMB's cannot be disabled in Windows without disabling File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks completely.

I believe that some computer on the VPN has set itself up as the master browser
of the network, so all SMB requests go to the VPN, regardless of the routing table.
The VPN master browser does not check the IP demanded, just the share-name,
and connects you to the named share.

Some measures that might help by modifying the properties of the VPN adapter:

Go to *Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections*,
enter the Properties of the VPN network adapter, then try the following.
When finished click OK.

- Disable "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks".
- Click on "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)", click the Properties button,
  click the *Advanced* button, position to the WINS tab and set
  "Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP".
  Click OK to return to the adapter's properties.
- Disable "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)".

If any of the above measures solved the problem, you could complain to the VPN
Support for having it set up in the first place when creating the VPN adapter.

---

The network-adapter option of
"File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" can be
disabled or enabled for a network adapter from the command-line,
for ease of use:

- For using PowerShell, see
  [Manage file and printer sharing using a script](https://superuser.com/questions/1385624/manage-file-and-printer-sharing-using-a-script)
- For a third-party utility, see
  [nvspbind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850)
  with
  [examples](https://ss64.com/nt/nvspbind.html).

Comment: But when I need to access it through the VPN I would need to enable them again, and again disable, and enable... But it might still help disabling the whole sharing. I’d rather understand why a master browser would affect this in any way though. I mean it’s easier to turn off vpn than change settings all the time since I need to access other servers through the VPN

Comment: When a master browser sets itself up, LAN manager forwards it all SMB connect requests. Each network on both adapters will have its own master browser, and the results for your computer are not always predictable. If you need to access shares on the VPN network, then you will need to undo the above. If this answer does indeed solve the basic problem, there might be a way to switch between adapter states more easily via scripts.

Comment: It of course would give a result since it would disable sharing, but as I mentioned that would be easier done by disabling the VPN. And that’s not reasonable either. So it doesn’t fix the problem. I need to be able to access servers behind the VPN and not at the same time through their own networks. This also doesn’t explain why the results for other machines would be predictable, or why network speed affects it.

Comment: The choice of the master browser might depend on the metrics in the routing table, which might be why the VPN always takes priority. In any case, I think I have well explained what you are seeing. You might explain more about how you are using the VPN: Is it only for sharing or also for internet access, and are you accessing shares on both networks?

Comment: I added some command-line commands for disabling/enabling file sharing,easier than using the GUI.

Comment: I think I have fully answered the question & bounty : "Windows using VPN even when using IP address to access share".

Comment: I haven’t seen an answer to how to fix this or what’s causing it. “Disable file sharing” isn’t a solution, or did I miss something? If it were I would have to accept “don’t use file sharing” or “don’t use files” also. The answer should explain how to stop this from happening *while using file sharing to other servers through the VPN*. How else will I transfer files between servers?

Comment: SMB just doesn't work this way - it's an old protocol that doesn't care about IP. To share files your way needs a newer mechanism that does use IP, for example FTP. SMB cannot be forced to use IP the way you want, unless with the brute-force method of switching file-sharing on/off in the adapter (which is less heavy than disconnect/reconnect the VPN), and even then it uses the share-name rather than the IP. We have to live with Windows the way it is, it's not open-source.