# Manage file and printer sharing using a script

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, powershell, network-shares, hyper-v

I have a problem with a Hyper-V internal network adapter and my external network (Intel Wi-Fi). Sometimes after starting a VM I lose access to my network shares both from my LAN and from VM itself (I get connection timeout, like port is closed). The firewall is configured manually with `gpedit.msc` to allow TCP/UDP trafic from both LAN and VM subnets (I can reach `postgres` fine from both LAN and VM).

I found a workaround, by disabling and re-enabling this `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` it seems to work (I need to do it on both adapters to restore connectivity for LAN and VM respectively).

Question: Is there any PowerShell/WMI/VBScript command to automate this? I found `Set-NetAdapter` but it doesn't seem to have any relevant options.

[image: Adapter option]

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know if the API to do that exists or not and I am just looking for a hint (registry path, name of PowerShell cmdlet, WMI path, etc..). How can I provide a code sample if I don't know if it's even possible?

Comment: You do your own research first. Then ask a question presenting your research and where you stuck implementing it yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill Duh it's `Enable-NetAdapterBinding`/`Disable-NetAdapterBinding
`

Comment: Reopened so you can self answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [`Disable-NetAdapterBinding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/Disable-NetAdapterBinding?view=win10-ps)/[`Enable-NetAdapterBinding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/enable-netadapterbinding?view=win10-ps)

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Your network adapter name" -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks"
Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Your network adapter name" -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks"
```

Alternatively you can use `-ComponentID ms_server`  instead of `-DisplayName "..."`

To get all adapters and available bindings use [`Get-NetAdapterBinding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterbinding?view=win10-ps)